# Showing amount of results with curl

Tags: php, html, curl, html-table, preg-match

Is it possible to only show like 4 results from a page received with curl?

This is my script :

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init ("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/top100.ws?list=2&scale=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match('#<tbody[^>]*>(.+?)</tbody>#is', $page, $matches);
foreach ($matches as &$match) {
    $match = $match;
}
echo '<table>';
    echo $matches[0];
echo '</table>';

?>
```

with a result of this

> > Leather vambraces Leather vambraces Free game item  9   12  3    +7% Bronze helm Bronze helm    Free game item  53  72  19   +6% Air rune Air
> >     rune  Free game item  22  30  8    +6% Varrock teleport Varrock
> >     teleport  Members' only item  969 1,255   286  +5% Teleport to house
> >     Teleport to house Members' only item  862 1,137   275  +5% Teak logs Teak
> >     logs  Members' only item  83  111 28   +5% Water orb Water orb    Members'
> >     only item 1,491   1,930   439  +5%

(That's just a piece normally there are like 100 results)

So is there way that i can only like display 4 results?

~~~~~~~Edit~~~~~~

Is there a way to place the result from this :"

```
Leather vambraces        9  12  3   +7%
Bronze helm                  53 72  19  +6%
Air rune                22  30  8   +6%
Varrock teleport        969 1,255   286 +5%
```

to this :

```
Leather vambraces        
Bronze helm                  
Air rune                
Varrock teleport
```

In a variable like `$item['name']`?

Comment: Epic useless code: `foreach ($matches as &$match) {
    $match = $match;
}` Have you changed this code for us, or is this actually what your code does?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I did not change anything. Only showed a small amount of the total result otherwise the post would be extremely long

Comment: In which case you can delete that foreach loop. It's doing nothing.

Comment: Is that text, pure text contained with just `$matches[0]` ? Or are they parts of `<td>`s or... ?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I dont exacly know what u mean but i think u mean the result of the matches? in that case its this : `<tr data-item-id="8007">
<td class="item">
<img src="http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_sprite.gif?id=8007" alt="Varrock teleport">
<a href="http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/Varrock_teleport/viewitem.ws?obj=8007">Varrock teleport</a>
</td>
<td>
<img src="http://www.runescape.com/img/itemdb/members-icon.png" alt="Members' only item" title="Members' only item">
</td>
<td>969</td>
<td>1,255</td>
<td>286</td>

<td class="positive">
+5%
</td>
</tr>`

Comment: Right, that's the contents of `$matches[0]` ?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP yes but without the style (normally its in a table)

Comment: @Jacob Brol are you check my answer

Comment: @JacobBrol I have added an answer below that's a modification of your original code, that shows the top 4 in a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (Updated)

```
 $ch = curl_init ("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/top100.ws?list=2&scale=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match('#<tbody[^>]*>(.+?)</tbody>#is', $page, $matches);
foreach ($matches as &$match) {
    $match = $match;
}
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $match);
        $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');  
        $thArray = $tdArray = $array = array();
        $tr = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');
        $i = 0;
        $s = 0;
        $k=5;
        echo "table";
        foreach ( $tr as $tr ) 
        {   

            $thArray[] = $tr->nodeValue;
            $td = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
            ini_set('max_execution_time', 99999999999999999999 );
            foreach( $td as $td ) 
             {
                 ini_set('max_execution_time', 99999999999999999999 );
                 $thAr[] = $td->nodeValue;          
                   if($s<=$k)
                   {
                       $thArrays[$i][] =$thAr[$s];
                       $n = $s;
                       $t=$s+6;
                   }
                   $s++;              
             }

              $s= $n+1;
              $k=$t;

              $i++;


        }
        echo "<table>";
        for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
        {   
        echo "<tr>";
        $row = $thArrays[$i];
        $ks  = count($row);

        for($k=0;$k<1;$k++)
        {
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row[$k];
            echo "</td>";           
        }
        echo "</tr>";       
        }
        echo "</table>";
        unset($thArray);
            unset($thArrays);

        exit;
```

Output like this format

```
Leather vambraces        
Bronze helm         
Air rune                
Varrock teleport
```

Comment: Tried it but i'm still getting all results

Comment: @Jacob Brol Now check it

Comment: Giving me a empty page:(

Comment: i forgot to put print_r now check it

Comment: if you want more rows if($i==4) just increase the value

Comment: Working! Is there also a simple way to put this in a table? like this? http://puu.sh/3V8i8.png

Comment: @Jacob Brol Now check it

Comment: Wouw perfect! If i ask to mutch just say it. But is there also a way that i like i only can show the names? Like leather vambraces bronze helm air rune varrock teleport? so it does not show the rest?

Comment: Also working:D! final question : and if i want to add the second row?

Sorry for my amount of questions

Comment: i dont understand.  if you want 2 nd row for($k=1;$k<2;$k++){  instend of for($k=0;$k<1;$k++){

Comment: just change the for loop conditions

Comment: Gettign a empty table.

Comment: @Jacob Brol are u got it

Comment: 2 td is empty so  try this for($k=2;$k<3;$k++){

Comment: Thank you everything is working now! Thanks for all your help !

Comment: Ya correct. but 2 nd td is empty so u change for($k=2;$k<3;$k++){

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this does what you want:

```
preg_match_all('#<tr[^>]*>(.+?)</tr>#is', $page, $matches);
$items = array();
unset($matches[0][0]);
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    $items[] = $match;
}
$items = array_slice($items,0,4); //Get first 4
echo '<table>';
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        echo $item;
    }
echo '</table>';
```